# Views in multi-node Couchbase cluster explained

Tags: couchbase, couchbase-view

I am new to Couchbase.

I have a 2 node Couchbase environment, and I have 20 documents (Articles in my application) stored in a bucket. I believe that there are 5 articles living physically in node 1 and the others are living in node 2 because when I shut down node 1, there are only 15 articles in my application's list.

I have an 'ordered by postdate' list in my application which I get results from a view like this: `...emit(doc.postdate)...`

Now, for some reason, the list in my application is always incorrect that some of the articles are not in the right position (not ordered by the post date).My only guess is that: node 1 has an index for the 5 articles and node 2 has an index for the other 15, they both order by the postdate field correctly in there own index, but after my application (using a .NET client library) get 5 from node 1 and 15 from node 2, it just 'concat' the two list into a full list 20,that's why I saw the wrong order in my application's article list.

So please tell my guess is wrong and my misunderstanding of Couchbase server, and also any other reasons I got a wrong ordered list? Any detailed information from the couchbase's architecture perspective will be really appreciated.

Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: Provide your mapping code, plus how you are calling it (params such as descending etc).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are ordering correctly. There are parameters to try ascending or descending to see if it makes any different order (if not, that means you are not using view ordering correctly). 
See [Ordering results](http://www.couchbase.com/docs//couchbase-devguide-2.0/ordering-results.html)

Also please provide your view mapping code.

e.g.

```
function (doc, meta) 
{
...
}
```